# Need to simulate 100 BLE devices in my vicinity

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, microchip

I want to test my application that is getting reports that it’s unusable when there are a lot of Bluetooth devices in the range. Since I work from a remote location, I cannot verify the issue.

I have tried certain things already but ultimately realized that having BLE ids advertised right at my location is the only way to debug and test the app in the future.

What is the easiest way and in the smallest form factor (if the solution is hardware) to simulate 100 Bluetooth devices? I have a budget, so I can buy certain hardware if that helps, as long as it's portable. :)

Comment: ESP32 is pretty cheap and capable of BLE

Comment: The question is whether you need all the devices in parallel or one after the other?

Comment: I need them in parellel

Answer (score 2):

You can use almost any BLE device and set it to use "static random address". What you do is that you set a new random address, advertise for a short time, abort the advertising and then set another address and start advertising again, and so on. This is supported at the HCI layer so any controller will work.

You can for example use my library at https://github.com/Emill/node-ble-host to do this. Use the static random address option as explained at https://github.com/Emill/node-ble-host/blob/master/docs/api/ble-manager.md#creating-a-blemanager-object.